# Wix Form Validation

Tags: javascript, velo

First off, I am a complete noob. I have just recently started getting good with python and have close to zero knowledge regarding javascript and corvid for wix. I am looking through documentation but I can't figure out how to do the following: When a user fills out a field, let's say a phone number field, how do you validate whether that field has any alphabetical characters or "+" or "-" etc or not?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#input1").onCustomValidation( (value, reject) => {
 if( input1 is anything but an integer ) {
      reject("Only Numbers. No '-', '.', '()', '+', or any alphabetical characters");
 }
  } );
});
```

I feel like I am close but have no idea. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To answer your question:

**Includes Function**

You would want to use the **.includes()** function native to javascript which returns a boolean of if it is or isn't included. If you need the string index of each occurrence you would need to use a for loop as shown below.

```
var string = "+54 2453-2534-242";

for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
  if(string.substr(i,1) === "-"){
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

[Includes Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

**Replace Function**

Below is an example of how to use this function.
If you wish to remove these or one of these characters you can use the **.replace()** function or the **.split()** and **.join()** functions.

```js
const string = "+53 573-2566-242";
const character_1 = "+";
const character_2= "-";

// Includes
console.log(string + ".includes(+):", string.includes(character_1));
console.log(string + ".includes(-):",string.includes(character_2));

// Replace Singular
var new_string = string.replace(character_1,'');
console.log(new_string);

// Replace Multiple
var new_string2 = string.split(character_2).join("");
console.log(new_string2);
```

[Replace Funtion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

If you are still stuck, please feel free to comment

*Edit*

To check if there are **any** alpha-numeric characters in a string. You can simply use the .replace() function and compare it. As seen below:

```js
var string = "abc546"; // Your Phone Number Input
var string_converted = string.replace(/\D/g,''); 

if(string !== string_converted){
  console.log("Contains Characters that are not of type NUMBER!");
  
  console.log(`${string} vs ${string_converted}`);
}
```

In your case, you could use the code below:

```js
$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#input1").onCustomValidation( (value, reject) => {
     // Assuing *value* is your input
     
     var converted = value.replace(/\D/g,'');
     if(value !== converted){
        // Regective Statment Here..
     }else{
        // All good! (No Alph-numeric Characters)
     }
     
  });
});
```

Comment: I am a complete idiot, I copied the wrong code. It should have looked like this:

`$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#input1").onCustomValidation( (value, reject) => {
 if( input1 is anything but an integer ) {
      reject("Only Numbers. No '-', '.', '()', '+', or any alphabetical characters");
 }
  } );
});`                            I wanted to know what goes in the if statement

Comment: Hey man, no problem. I am going to update my answer to more accurately address your problem.